# Can TCC-100/100I Series Industrial RS-232 to RS-422/485 converters with optional 2 kV isolation convert RS485 to RS232?

Tags: sensor, rs485, rs232, modbus

I want to convert RS485 to RS232 to connect it to a Moxa Nport 5610 - 16 port RS-232 Ethernet serial device server.

Can I use a TCC-100/100I Series Industrial RS-232 to RS-422/485 converter to convert RS-485 to RS-232?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both interfaces are bidirectional, **yes**.